# JMeter - 50% split and take relevant path

Tags: jmeter

I am not an expert in JMeter but hope you can help.

How does one execute a test plan where based on a CSV input of users, I want 50% of them to go down 1 flow (for each user - do stuff) and the other 50% to do another flow of logic?

I'm not fussed about if it's at random (That would be good) of users in the file or sequentially going through it and splitting at the 50% mark - but do want to know how to do this type of process within a test plan?

I am trying to create an even (or almost even) type of distribution "load" - some go one path, some go another path. Simple.

Let me give you a walk through:

- we have students.
- students have different tests.
- half of them I want each student to do ALL tests
- half of them I want each student to do 1 test (based on some JSON that has been parsed which gives us the list of tests from the web end)

Also, is it possible where if I have a jmx file that contains, say, 10 controllers (these would be tests), I can pick one at random and then return back to the parent? Maybe in here a decision can be made to do next test or not and if next test then... cycle to the next one

Thoughts?

I am using JMeter 5.3 if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo (%) operator on the studentID (or 'number' or 'rownumber' -- whatever is handy).

If the output is odd, send a request to scenario a (first 50%), and if even, send a request for scenario b (second 50%).

// Example in PsuedoJava:

```
int id = myStudentIDNumber; 

if(id % 2 == 0){ // Remainder is 0, so even number 
  fetch(mywebsite/api1); 
} else { // Remainder is 1, so odd number 
  fetch(mywebsite/api2); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this? This would help!

Comment: Modulo operator returns the remainder when dividing. Dividing by two will leave you a remainder of one or zero, aka odd or even. I updated my answer to include an example. Please let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Sure but i don't think this i can incorporate in the JMeter test plan I have. I am going down the route of the throughput controller however it only seems to take just 1 of the branches and not the other even though the 2 branches are split 50/50.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)(s) to distribute the executions.
Set the **Based on** to `Percent executions` and set the value to 50.

[image]

**Note**: Set the Sharing mode in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) appropriately

[image]

You can use a [Random Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller) to pick a random child from the sub-controllers and samplers.

Comment: thanks. So it's a little unclear. I have a ThreadGroup that reads CSV. I then have an if logic, which is what I want based on value from CSV. Now within this, I need to add the throughput controller (50%)? And then within this throughput controller, then what do I do, since I need 50% to go down one branch and the other to go the other branch?

Comment: So I am trying to use this however it seems it only ever goes through the first branch/throughput controller and never the 2nd one even though it is a 50/50 split. Thoughts? I should also mention that the throughput controller is under a conditional check to see if the data column has a certain value (i.e "IsValid") from which is under the thread group. So: TG -> IsValid -> Throughput1 and Throughput2

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of implementing your scenario, depending on what is your design the options are in:

1. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) which controls how often its children to be executed (either in percentage of total executions or in absolute values)
2. [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) which acts like a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) in programming languages  - this guy seems to be the most appropriate for your use case. Moreover it can run a random child if you supply [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) as the input
3. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide/) - which combines above 2 approaches and provides easy way of